# What is the meaning of "is that of"? How to understand it?

Tags: phrases, computing

I am reading *[Distributed Systems Concept And Design](http://www.cdk5.net/wp/)*. I don't understand the following sentence on page 613, especially the `is that of` phrase.

> The state si in the global state S corresponding to the cut C is that of pi immediately after the last event processed by pi in the cut.

Can someone explain a bit how to understand `is that of`? I found another example:

> In all other states in the US, a domestic corporation's legal status is that of a foreign corporation.

Comment: I suspect that in the first sentence a "of" is missing between "state" and "si". Anyway, it means "is the same of", "coincides with" or "is equal to".

Comment: This question is better asked on  [ell.se]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The state si in the global state S corresponding to the cut C is that of pi immediately after the last event processed by pi in the cut.
>
> In all other states in the US, a domestic corporation's legal status is that of a foreign corporation.

The word *that* is an anaphoric pronoun in these examples. This means that we understand what *that* refers to through words that occurred earlier in the discourse. The reason it is difficult to decode in the first example is because the noun *state* is followed by an appositive proper noun, *si*, and then modified by a very long Prepositional Phrase: *in the global ... cut C* ’. The word *that* in the first example should be interpreted as *the state*:

> **The state** si in the global state S corresponding to the cut C is **the state** of pi immediately after the last event processed by pi in the cut.

Similarly:

> In all other states in the US, a domestic corporation's **legal status** is the **legal status**  of a foreign corporation.

The word *that* in each case is just 'referring' back to a previous noun in the sentence. In short ‘*is that of* ’ should be interpreted as ‘*is the X of* ’ - where *the X* is co-referrential  with a previous noun in the text.